# Транслитерация имени загрузочного файла php

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста, где ошибка, почему не работает транслитерация имени файла?

```
<?php
$s = $_FILES['passport_file']['name'];
function translit($s) {
  $s = (string) $s;
  $s = strip_tags($s);
  $s = str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), " ", $s);
  $s = preg_replace("/\s+/", ' ', $s);
  $s = trim($s);
  $s = function_exists('mb_strtolower') ? mb_strtolower($s) : strtolower($s);
  $s = strtr($s, array('а'=>'a','б'=>'b','в'=>'v','г'=>'g','д'=>'d','е'=>'e','ё'=>'e','ж'=>'j','з'=>'z','и'=>'i','й'=>'y','к'=>'k','л'=>'l','м'=>'m','н'=>'n','о'=>'o','п'=>'p','р'=>'r','с'=>'s','т'=>'t','у'=>'u','ф'=>'f','х'=>'h','ц'=>'c','ч'=>'ch','ш'=>'sh','щ'=>'shch','ы'=>'y','э'=>'e','ю'=>'yu','я'=>'ya','ъ'=>'','ь'=>''));
  $s = preg_replace("/[^0-9a-z-_ ]/i", "", $s); 
  $s = str_replace(" ", "-", $s);
  return $s;
}
$uploaddir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/files/users/'.$_POST['id'].'/passport/';
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['passport_file']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir . $s);
?>
```

Comment: Потому что функция translit __не вызывается__?

Answer (score 1):

> Подскажите пожалуйста, где ошибка

В вашем вопросе не содержится вызова функции `translit()`, и предполагается, что вы её вызываете, но в вопросе забыли это указать. В таком случае, вероятнее всего ошибка при преобразовании строки функцией `mb_strtolower($s)` *(по крайней мере, на локалке именно в этом месте происходило искажение входящей строки)*. Исправить можно явным указанием кодировки: `mb_strtolower($s, 'UTF-8')`.

Но лучше было бы оптимизировать эту функцию, т.к. в ней слишком много лишних, не связанных с транслитом, манипуляций. Как вариант, можно использовать регулярные выражения всего лишь один раз *(вместо нескольких, и вместо всех остальных сопутствующих функций)*:

```
$s = "Название файла\n\rНазвание файла\n\r";
var_dump( translit($s) ); // 'nazvanie-fayla-nazvanie-fayla'


function translit($s)
{
    $search = [
        'а','б','в','г','д','е','ё','ж','з','и','й',
        'к','л','м','н','о','п','р','с','т','у','ф',
        'х','ц','ч','ш','щ','ы','э','ю','я','ъ','ь','\s+'
    ];
    $replace = [
        'a','b','v','g','d','e','e','j','z','i','y',
        'k','l','m','n','o','p','r','s','t','u','f',
        'h','c','ch','sh','shch','y','e','yu','ya','','','-'
    ];
    $search = array_map(function($i){ return "~$i~iu"; }, $search);

    return preg_replace($search, $replace, trim($s));
}
```

Comment: Я думаю, что помимо описания ошибки можно написать в ответе, что функцию все-таки следует вызвать.

Comment: @u_mulder согласен - подправил.